# How to use os.remove to delete more than one file during single app run

Tags: python

I am trying to write simple app which allows download youtube videos and convert them to mp3 using pytube and moviepy. In first step I download mp4 file then convert it to mp3 and delete mp4 file, but unfortunately when I try to download second file my app convert file to mp3 and crash but doesn't delete this file, the only way to download another file and delete it is to restart app. Does anybody know how I can fix this issue. I tried to google this but didn't find anything usefull.

```py
 def choose_dir_and_download(self):
        try:
            user_link = self.source.text()
            yt = YouTube(user_link)

            # Inform about that file is downloading
            self.completed_info.setText('')
            self.length.setText('')
            self.title_and_download_info.setText('Downloading')

            folder_path = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(self, 'Select Folder')

            to_download = yt.streams.get_highest_resolution()
            VideoFileClip(to_download.download(folder_path + '/'))

            cleared_title = delete_illegal_chars(yt.title)
            video_to_convert = VideoFileClip(folder_path + '/' + cleared_title + '.mp4')
            video_to_convert.audio.write_audiofile(os.path.join(folder_path + '/' + cleared_title + '.mp3'))

            # Print information about downloaded file
            self.completed_info.setText('Completed: ')
            self.length.setText('Duration: ' + time.strftime('%H:%M:%S', time.gmtime(yt.length)))
            self.title_and_download_info.setText(yt.title)

            self.delete_file(video_to_convert, folder_path, yt)
        except pytube.exceptions.RegexMatchError:
            self.title_and_download_info.setText('Invalid link')

 def delete_file(self, file_to_delete, path, yt):
     file_to_delete.close()
     os.remove(path + '/' + delete_illegal_chars(yt.title) + '.mp4')
```

If I comment line which deletes file everything is fine, but I really want to delete this mp4 file.

Comment: don't recreate the logic to find the path, just calculate it once and pass it in.  also, are there no contexts for your functions?  can you just use `with ...:` instead of handling the close yourself?

Comment: Also, take a look at finally, and perhaps have a second try block for after you have created the file https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#finally

Comment: I created variable with path to my file and passed it as an argument to 'delete_file' function and even checked twice if it isn't changed by accident at any moment of running my app, but it didn't help. Like I said before, first file downloads, converts and deletes properly but different file only downloads and converts.

Comment: Can you provide the traceback?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/qyLvN8A

Comment: The exit code identifies a STATUS_STACK_BUFFER_OVERRUN, which essentially is a stack overflow. Unfortunately it's a very broad error that is raised for many reasons; in your case it may be that the buffer you're writing to is pointing to the wrong place or maybe it's exhausted. I'm afraid you might need to do some Win debugging to find the real culprit. However a good start could be to add more verbosity in the code, to inspect what's happening at each step.